# how to add or insert new user via admin login in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-routing, laravel-6

I have read all the similar question but none of them solved my problem. my question is how to insert a new user via admin users. let me explain what I did so far.

first, I created a user system using artisan method in laravel 6
then I inserted one more column to users table as "is_admin" in database
then I inserted one user 'admin' through register module of laravel
then I disabled register module with 
'`Auth::routes(['register'=>false]);`
in the admin module, I pasted a code from register.blade.php in user.blade.php file. everything seems ok but when I press submit button in user.blade.php file nothing gets inserted in the database. I tried to change routes.etc. then i found problem is in
 `<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal row-fluid" action="{{ route('register') }}">`

The route in the action attribute of form is not working .please help I am struggling from last three days to get it done.

Comment: What happen if you  enable the register module again and submit your form?

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe if Auth::routes(['register'=>false]); then it show this error "Route [register] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\sakhawatapp\resources\views\partials\user.blade.php)"  while calling user.blade.php file . and if i set it true Auth::routes(['register'=>true]) user.blade view get displayed so when i press submit button it routes me to home page(dashboard) without inserting form data in database.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use `register` route for storing user. Create a new route, controller and method for this. The method will lool like this:

```
public function store(\Request $request){
        $inputs=$request->all();
        $inputs['password']=Hash::make($inputs['password']);
        User::create($inputs);
    }
```

Do the further changes as you need like admin flag or others.

Comment: Thank you Amimul Ehshan  for your answer , i will surely try this one to get the desired result